# Pull jquery string from php value

Tags: php, jquery, twitter

I am using Twitterfetcher of [Jason Mayes](http://codepen.io/jasonmayes/pen/Ioype) which works perfectly, except that I need to add the twitter_id coming from a PHP value.
Probably you all out there have that answer in a second:

This is the jQuery Code, the number is de Twitter ID. If I fill it out as a string, it works

```
twitterFetcher.fetch('409855577100005376', 'twitter-feed', 3, true, false, true, '', false, handleTweets3);
```

But I need to put in de Twitter ID dynamically, with the value coming from php.

```
<?php 
$twitter_id= '409855577100005376';
?>

`<script type="text/javascript"> jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
twitterFetcher.fetch($twitter_id, 'twitter-feed', 3, true, false, true, '', false, handleTweets3);
</script>
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, PHP is processed before JS

```
<?php 
$twitter_id= '409855577100005376';
?>

<script type="text/javascript"> jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
twitterFetcher.fetch('<?php echo $twitter_id; ?>', 'twitter-feed', 3, true, false, true, '', false, handleTweets3);
</script>
```

Comment: After the echo a semicolumn may help? (;)

Comment: Or use `<?=` and skip the semicolon.  Go green.

Comment: Thank you Pwner, the apostrophes were very important in this one, so your answer made my day!

Answer (score 2):

this line

```
 twitterFetcher.fetch($twitter_id
```

you need to print the var...

```
 twitterFetcher.fetch(<?php print $twitter_id;?>
```

Comment: this should work, you just have to insert the php tag inside the script

Comment: Almost... it also needed the apostrophes

Answer (score 1):

The other answers work well enough if you plan to have the JavaScript inline in the `</head>` of each page; however if you need to use the `var` in a separate file the following might be preferable.

In the `</head>` section of the PHP page you can include a namespaced var, assign the value via PHP and then you can recall it anywhere in your JavaScript File like so:

**PHP File**

```
<head>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.NAMESPACE = {};
        NAMESPACE.twitter_id = "<?php echo '1234567890'; ?>";
    </script>
    ...
</head>
```

**JS FILE**

```
...
twitterFetcher.fetch(
    NAMESPACE.twitter_id,
    'twitter-feed',
    3,
    true,
    false,
    true,
    '',
    false,
    handleTweets3
);
...
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry for just commenting on 1 answer, I tried them all and the id seems to have taken. 
I get another error, this time concerning handleTweets at the end of the fetch (I removed the 3 just to be more clear).

 `function handleTweets(tweets){
  var x = tweets.length;
  var n = 0;
  var element = document.getElementById('user-feed');
  var html = '<ul id="twitter" class="newsticker">';
  while(n < x) {
    html += '<li>' + tweets[n] + '</li>';
    n++;
  }
  html += '</ul>';
  element.innerHTML = html;
 }`

I only get output:
    `<ul id="twitter" class="newsticker"></ul>`

Comment: @inTOWN You should start a new question for that issue as it is a separate issue. Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it helped you.

Comment: Is it really new? The problem only occurs once I don't put the id in the fetcher directly? So if I just type the number, it all works fine.

Comment: @inTOWN Sounds like the ID isn't being picked up by the script. Have you tried logging the ID via console?

Comment: I do see a script called 418467466285547500 with an error in it:
    `twitterFetcher.callback({"headers":{"status":404,"message":"Widget configuration is not found."}});`
Working on the console thingie now

Comment: console.log(409855577100005376);
Seems to work (sorry for the different numbers, I tried several.

Comment: I got it... it needed brackets:
`twitterFetcher.fetch(<?php echo '\''. $twitter_id . '\'' ?>, 'user-feed',8, true, true, true, '', false, handleTweets2, false);`

So what do I do with marking an answer as accepted if:
- all answers were basically right?

Comment: @inTOWN Awesome, glad you got it working! Whichever answer you ended up using and / or helped you the most.

Comment: Well, that would be the one below, but also a big up to you for assisting me so greatly!